# ToggleButton/Button turns off after rolling off the bottom of the list

Tags: android

I have a problem - my buttons, togglebuttons, textviews (Everting) changes after swiping down a list. Anyone of you have the same problem?

Im using a few PageViewers, simple list and thats all... Thay change always after hidding in list. Strange...

Anyone?

Comment: This is probably due to the views being recycled and you not keeping the state, but it's hard to say with any certainty without seeing the code.

Comment: OK, solved - BIG THANKS for you, because i found bug in code after you said "views being recycled and you not keeping the state". And Android Developers says we must check in "public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent)" if view is null. And thats all ! :D